# POI excel skip the first row

Tags: java, excel, spring-boot, apache-poi

I made poi excel read, upload and save into DB but when I check my DB, excel parsing db without first row. I tried to change code but it doesn't work so I put the my original code. please help!

```
public static List<Product> excelToExcelEntity(InputStream inputStream) {
        try {
            Workbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(inputStream);
            Sheet sheet = wb.getSheet(SHEET);
            Iterator<Row> rows = sheet.iterator();

            List<Product> entities = new ArrayList<Product>();

            int rowNumber = 0;
            while (rows.hasNext()) {
                Row currentRow = rows.next();

                if (rowNumber == 0) {
                    rowNumber++;
                    continue;
                }
                Iterator<Cell> cellsInRow = currentRow.iterator();
                Product excelEntity = new Product();
                DataFormatter formatter = new DataFormatter();
                int cellIdx = 0;

                while (cellsInRow.hasNext()) {
                    Cell currentCell = cellsInRow.next();
                switch:
               ---
                break;}
                    cellIdx++;
                }
                entities.add(excelEntity);
            }
            wb.close();
            return entities;
```

Comment: please update your question to include what the purpose of the code is supposed to do. I have no idea what you want to happen.  You probably copied the code off some site without clearly understanding it, and I assume that the if statement is there to skip the first row where the column headers usually are. Also, you're code seems to have other problems, so update your question and title to include that.

Comment: `Row row = rows.next(); int rowNum = row.getRowNum(); if (rowNum != 0) { entities.add(excelEntity); }`

Answer (score 1):

```
if (rowNumber == 0) {
    rowNumber++;
    continue;
}
```

remove/comment above block code, in here ***continue*** will skip further execution and goes back to next element from the list, in your case it's skipping first row.

Comment: If I remove those code. I get "Cannot get a numeric value from a text cell" error.

Comment: your first row contains header or data ?, if header then you might want skip else you need to parse it correct format

Comment: it is data. it skipped first row of data.

Comment: looks like data in excel is in text format, try "currentCell.getStringCellValue()" and format it later to the expected one

Comment: [CELL](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Cell.html), you can refer here

Comment: that's what I'm using now. currentCell.getStringCellValue()

Comment: try to update the cell format in your excel to text, or else use Data formatter object

Comment: DataFormatter formatter = new DataFormatter(); this is what I'm using now..

Comment: try `String data=formatter.formatCellValue(cell);`

Comment: `code

                        case 1:
                            excelEntity.setProductName(formatter.formatCellValue(currentCell));
                            break;
`
this is what am I using now.